# How to connect STM32F429 with AD9748?

Tags: microcontroller

I have a problem with connecting STM32F429 with a DAC (AD9748). I found that STM32 has pins PA4 and PA5 that could be used as `DAC_OUT`. I have been trying to look for this interface and I am not able to proceed forward.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me proceed.

Comment: The "DAC_OUT" is for the STM32's internal DAC, probably.

Comment: Yes it is for the internal DAC.

Answer (score 2):

DACOUT on STM32 is the analog output of the internal DAC. The Analog Devices DAC needs a parallel interface, you could use just GPIO or connect it to the external memory bus.

Comment: Yes using GPIO's would help me. Also, is this the case for connecting AD9601(ADC) to stm32f429 or any other possible way as i see 3 12-bit ADC's on stm32f429.                                   Thank you.

Comment: Again, if you want to use an external ADC then you need gpio pins.  If you want to use the micro's internal ADC then use the ADC pins.

Comment: I think connecting a 200MSPS anything to a STM32 needs something a bit more than just GPIO pins.